# WCF Web Service Error (Could not find default endpoint element that references contract)

Tags: web-services, wcf

I've spent hours trying to figure out this particular error and have had no luck.

I keep getting an error reading like I'm missing an endpoint and I'm new to WCF web Services so I'm not sure what direction to look. Anyway, The error reads.

Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference1.ServiceContract' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I create the object like this and then add a method.

ServiceReference1.ServiceContractClient test = new ServiceReference1.ServiceContractClient();
var connecting = test.Connect();

I have endpoints in my web.config file of the WcfProject. Here's my web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
      <sessionState cookieless="false" mode="InProc"/>
      <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
      </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="RestBinding"></binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="WcfRestService1.Service">
                <endpoint name="ServiceBinding" contract="WcfRestService1.IService" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RestBinding" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <endpoint address="basic" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfRestService1.IService" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://servername/WcfRestService1/Service.svc" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="RestBehavior">
                    <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <client>
            <endpoint name="Default"
                      address="http://servername/WcfRestService1/Service.svc"
                      binding="webHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="RestBinding"
                      behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior"
                      contract="WcfRestService1.IService" />
        </client>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I'm not sure what i need.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can not consume REST service using Service Proxy generated either by using Visual studio add service reference feature or using svcutil.exe. You need to use WebClient, HttpWebRequest or any other third party library capable of making http calls.